# How does SQL Server With READUNCOMMITTED behave on VIEWS?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view which contains a join of multiple tables. If I use `WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)` on the `SELECT FROM View`, will this propagate and apply to tables that are joined by the view or not ?

Answer (score 2):

The isolation is only for the table that it applies to.

Consider the following. In one session, set up the table and view:

```
create table x (a int, b varchar(10))

create table y (c int, d varchar(10))

insert into x (a, b) values (1, 'Q')
insert into x (a, b) values (2, 'W')
insert into x (a, b) values (3, 'E')

insert into y (c, d) values (1, 'A')
insert into y (c, d) values (2, 'S')
insert into y (c, d) values (3, 'D')


create view v_test
as
select x.a, x.b, y.d
from x with (readuncommitted)
     inner join 
     y
     on x.a = y.c
```

Select from the view from session1:

select *
from v_test

```
a       b       c
----    ----    ----
1       Q       A
2       W       S
3       E       D
```

Now open another session, and fire up a transaction, updating only x at first:

```
begin transaction

update x
set b = 'R'
where a = 1
```

Go back to session 1, and execute the view. You'll now get this:

```
a       b       d
----    ---     ---
1       R       A
2       W       S
3       E       D
```

Note the new value for b in the first row.

Go back to session 2, with the transaction still open, update y:

```
update y
set d = 'F'
where c = 1
```

and then try querying the view back in session 1:

```
select *
from v_test
```

(You'll find it seems to be taking a rather long time.)

With the query still executing, go back to session 2 and commit the transaction:

(Session2 looks like this now:

```
begin transaction

update x
set b = 'R'
where a = 1

update y
set d = 'F'
where c = 1

commit
```

)

Look back at session1 and the results will now appear with this:

```
a       b       d
---     ---     ---
1       R       F
2       W       S
3       E       D
```

with the new value for d in the first row.

So, long story a little longer, the WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) is not propagated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was answered, to the contrary, here: ["SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED" and views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099960/set-transaction-isolation-level-read-uncommitted-and-views)

But they could have been wrong, I haven't done your steps yet Patrick, if you're correct then you should inform the folks on that thread!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the example from Patrick with `readuncommitted` on both tables you will see that it will work even when the transaction is in progress.
An you can also run the example without the `with readuncommitted` inside the view but pass `with readuncommitted` to the select from the view and it will propagate down to the select in the view if passed to the view.
ex.

```
select *
from v_test with (readuncommitted)
```