# "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED" and views

Tags: sql, sql-server

If you set `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`
on a stored procedure that selects from view which has a complex select from multiple tables,  will this place `READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction isolation level on all the tables in that view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **session** will be set to be `READ UNCOMMITTED` - this will apply to all tables queried in the session (whether through a view or not), as long as this isolation level is set.